# How can I make this bitwise code work?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

bitwise operators only work on integers in PHP and the maximum size of an integer is 2^63 on 64bit servers. If I create a value greater than that it will cast my variable to a float and bitwise operators will stop functioning. I have the following example:

```
<?php

$CAN_DANCE = 2;

$CAN_SING = 4;

$CAN_PLAY = 8;

$CAN_BEGOD = pow(2,64);

$userperms =  $CAN_PLAY | $CAN_DANCE | $CAN_SING | $CAN_BEGOD;

if($userperms & $CAN_DANCE)
    echo 'This will work';

if($userperms & $CAN_BEGOD)
    echo 'This will not work';

?>
```

Naturally it will return true for the first check as thats less than 2^63 however for the latter I assign it to 2^64 which is too great for an integer and it incorrectly returns false. Is there any way to make it work for greater than 2^63? Otherwise I will only be able to use bitperms for upto 63 different items only.

Comment: That is still 64 different items. You're forgetting 2^0.

Comment: Are you sure about that? integer | 0 would return 0 which would be interpreted as false would it not? Either way do you know a solution? If so it would be much appreciated, Thanks! Dave

Comment: "Otherwise I will only be able to use bitperms for upto 63 different items only." Yes, but really: When you need bitmasks with 64 different flags (you forgot 2^0 as already mentioned), then you definitely did something wrong. Use different bitmask for different task and make sure no task requires more than 64 different flags

Comment: but if I have 100 pages I don't know how I could have more than one bitmask for each one. I know vBulletin uses bitwise operators to accomplish bitperms, I wonder what they do

Answer (score 1):

[GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) comes to mind, this is encapsulated ([see full code/demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tT0l1Q)):

```
$CAN_DANCE = Gmp(2);

$CAN_SING = Gmp(4);

$CAN_PLAY =  Gmp(8);

$CAN_BEGOD = Gmp(2)->pow(64);    

$userperms = Gmp($CAN_PLAY)->or($CAN_DANCE, $CAN_SING, $CAN_BEGOD);    

if($userperms->and($CAN_DANCE)->bool())
    echo 'This will work', "\n";

if($userperms->and($CAN_BEGOD)->bool())
    echo 'This will work', "\n";
```

This will work with much larger numbers, however, the numbers are resources (`Gmp::number()`) or strings (`(string) Gmp`) and as long as each instance lives, the `Gmp` object as well.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_init() in test.php on line 42 :(

Comment: You need to install the gmp extension linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Because this function return int, maybe you could you use the gmp_pow() function,
and to calculate the rusults you can use the gmp_or() and for the if steatments you can use gmp_and()

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a bit array:

```
$bitArray = array();
$bitArray[0] = $word0;
$bitArray[1] = $word1;
. 
.
.
```

If you need $nFlags bits and $bitsPerWord = 64, then you'll create $nFlags/$bitsPerWord words.